# Phone number masking in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on react native where a driver calls to the customer from the app. But the dialed number is visible in the dial pad which is not good for customer privacy. So is there option in react native for masking the number?
Currently i use this for calling

```
Linking.openURL(`tel:${this.props.element.Phone}`)
```

Comment: You want to start a call on the user's device but want to hide the phone number? It's up to the device to display the phone number or not during the call, in the history, or when your app opens the `tel:` link. You have no control over what the user's device chooses to do when you delegate something like a call to the OS. You'll need to implement VoIP in your app to avoid exposing the customer's phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do otherwise. You cannot make a call without the user consent (for example iOS shows an alert containing the phone number, and Android redirects the user to the phone app with the number prefilled).

For that you can use [react-native-immediate-phone-call](https://github.com/wumke/react-native-immediate-phone-call)

```
import RNImmediatePhoneCall from 'react-native-immediate-phone-call';
...
RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall('0123456789');
...
```